Remove Committed files from local git repository
I am working on a local git repository project that is not linked or hosted on any remote repository. I actually have to submit this repo as a project but I accidentally committed a .class file on it. Could it be tracked? If yes, will it get removed if I simply delete that file from my repository folder? If no, is there any other way?

If you committed the file then it is currently being tracked by git. As talked about in How do I make Git forget about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore? - to make git stop tracking the file, (to make the file not show up in the repo when clone), you can use:
git rm --cached <your file>.class

And then make a new commit.

Thank you very much @Mason Peterson , it worked.
